# Regarding Android auto application development resources folder

Tags: android, android-auto

If we are targeting our application to support android auto too, how can I have the Auto layout look different from the phone/tablet layout?

In order to achieve that, is there an option to put a separate res folder inside resources?
And I want to know how the UI will render on the screen of Vehicle as the apk is inside mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have a bad news for you: you don't get to touch the Android Auto's UI at all.

There are only two kind of Apps you can develop for Auto,

> *`Audio apps` that allow users to browse and play music and spoken audio content in the car.
>   *`Messaging apps` that receive incoming notifications, read messages aloud via text-to-speech, and send replies via voice input in the car.

For Audio app, they require you to provide a service which they can call and get information, contents from your app. (Like `Delegate` in iOS?)

For Messaging app, your notifications would be shown as long as contain the CarExtender.

So.. no custom UI, no custom App.

p.s. UI are drawn on phone and send to car dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

We have an update on this, now we are able to develop media apps, messaging apps, navigation/parking/charging apps.
For more details refer this [click here](https://developer.android.com/cars)